# ffmpeg generates random length video when using libx265

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libx265

I am using `ffmpeg` to record my outdoor camera video stream. The below script works pretty well to split the stream to be 1 hour video.

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://username:password@1.1.1.1/stream1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 3600 -segment_format mkv -segment_atclocktime 1 -strftime 1 ~/onedrive/camera/%Y%m%dT%H-%M-%S.mkv 2> ~/projects/ip-camera/upload.log
```

The only issue is the video file is too big, around 1GB for 1hour video file.

So I am trying to use `libx265` to compress the video

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://username:password@1.1.1.1/stream1 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -acodec copy -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 3600 -segment_format mkv -segment_atclocktime 1 -strftime 1 ~/onedrive/camera/%Y%m%dT%H-%M-%S.mkv 2> ~/projects/ip-camera/upload.log
```

The strange thing is now `ffmpeg` is generating random length video, between 5 minutes to 10 minutes for each video file.

What's wrong with my updated script? Couldn't `ffmpeg` generate 1-hour length video just as before by initial script?

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue when dealing with segmentation and transcoding simultaneously is keyframes (or I-frames). When segmenting, `ffmpeg` will ideally split the video at keyframes to avoid corruption or unplayable segments.

In your initial command, you used `-vcodec copy`, which does a straight copy without transcoding. Therefore, the natural keyframe intervals from the source are retained, and `ffmpeg` was probably segmenting on those keyframes that conveniently existed around the 1-hour mark.

However, when you introduced `libx265`, the encoding process could introduce keyframes at different intervals than the source or your desired segmentation point.

To solve this:

1. **Force keyframes**: You can force keyframes at specific intervals, which can help in determining when to split the video. For example, to set keyframes every 10 seconds (assuming 30 fps), you'd use `-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)"`. Adjust the `10` as needed based on your video's framerate.
2. **Tune for zero-latency**: Add `-tune zerolatency` for real-time applications.
3. **Preset**: You might want to specify a preset. x265 has presets that determine the compression-speed trade-off. Slower presets will compress more (smaller output file) but will take longer. Common presets are `ultrafast`, `superfast`, `veryfast`, `faster`, `fast`, `medium`, `slow`, `slower`, `veryslow`. The default is `medium`. For faster encoding (at the expense of a slightly larger file size), you can try `-preset fast`.

Combining these, your command would look something like:

```bash
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://username:password@1.1.1.1/stream1 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -preset fast -tune zerolatency -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)" -acodec copy -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 3600 -segment_format mkv -segment_atclocktime 1 -strftime 1 ~/onedrive/camera/%Y%m%dT%H-%M-%S.mkv 2> ~/projects/ip-camera/upload.log
```

Comment: thanks for the shared knowledge. I applied your script, but it is still the same.

Comment: Just as a test, try outputting to MP4 instead of MKV and see if the issue persists. Sometimes, specific container formats can have quirks with certain codecs. @new2cpp

Comment: change to `mp4`, it generates hundreds of 0 size videos

Comment: So now, instead of doing everything in one command, first capture the stream, and then segment it in a second command. Capture the stream: `ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://username:password@1.1.1.1/stream1 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -preset fast -tune zerolatency ~/onedrive/camera/temp.mkv
`, and then segment the video: `ffmpeg -i ~/onedrive/camera/temp.mkv -c copy -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 3600 -segment_format mkv -strftime 1 ~/onedrive/camera/%Y%m%dT%H-%M-%S.mkv` @new2cpp

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it worked for me before by 2 steps conversion. I am trying to find a way by 1 step only. Thanks anyway.

Comment: please show how to do this in one step only